# How to toggle a content of the single element in React JS?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks, toggle

I'm trying to implement toggle function in React JS, so when a user clicks on the title its content/text should be visible. I was able to create toggle function, but when I click on the title all texts are shown, for example, if I click on Title1 - Text1, Text2, Text3, and Text4 are shown also, instead of the only Text1.

[this is link to my codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-n4c13?file=/src/App.js)

My code:

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: "services",
    key: "1",
    title: "Title1",
    text: "Text1."
  },
  {
    id: "services",
    key: "2",
    title: "Title2",
    text: "Text2."
  },
  {
    id: "services",
    key: "3",
    title: "Title3",
    text: "Text3."
  },
  {
    id: "services",
    key: "4",
    title: "Title4",
    text: "Text4"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [toggled, toggle] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(({ title, text }) => {
        return (
          <>
            <h1 onClick={() => toggle(toggled => !toggled)}>{title} </h1>
            {!toggled ? (
              <>
                <p>{text}</p>
              </>
            ) : null}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I want to do is when the user clicks on Title1, only Text1 to appear, not all other Texts. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated,

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the boolean values of `true`/`false` in your component's `toggled` state, you can store the `key` from the `data` array instead.

Then, you can conditionally render the `text` below `h1` based on the current `toggled` state

```
export default function App() {
  const [toggled, toggle] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(({ title, text, key }) => {
        return (
          <>
            <h1 onClick={() => toggle(key)}>{title} </h1>
            {toggled ===key ? (
              <>
                <p>{text}</p>
              </>
            ) : null}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have forked your demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-ilujf).

Comment: Thank you so much, marking your answer as correct, this is exactly what I wanted.